# Assert the label in a UITableViewCell with EarlGrey 2

Tags: swift, earlgrey

Trying to assert that the first cell in the table view contains the string "first":

```
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_kindOfClass(UITableViewCell.self))
  .atIndex(0)
  .assert(grey_text("First"))
```

Failure:

```
  "Description Glossary" :   {
    "M" : "((kindOfClass('UILabel') || kindOfClass('UITextField') || kindOfClass('UITextView')) && hasText('First'))",
    "E" : "<App.SubclassCell:0x7fa0c011d600; isAccessible=N; AX.id='Subclass Cell'; AX.frame={{0, 88}, {414, 56}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 116}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitButton'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{0, 0}, {414, 56}}; opaque; alpha=1; text=''>",
    "S" : "kindOfClass('UILabel'), kindOfClass('UITextField'), kindOfClass('UITextView')"
  },
  "User Info" :   {
    "NSLocalizedDescription" : "Assertion with matcher [M] failed: UI element [E] failed to match the following matcher(s): [S]"
  },
```

How do I confirm that a specific index of the table view contains certain text?